# Display time based on country in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I've used timestamp behavior to display time and it works fine. How can the time display based on country?

Answer (score 2):

Your question it is rather general. Your should take a look at internationalization http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-i18n.html#internationalization and Data formattimg http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-formatting.html#data-formatting as you can see  you can localize date fornmat

```
  Yii::$app->formatter->locale = 'en-US';
  echo Yii::$app->formatter->asDate('2014-01-01'); // output: January 1, 2014

  Yii::$app->formatter->locale = 'de-DE';
  echo Yii::$app->formatter->asDate('2014-01-01'); // output: 1. Januar 2014

  Yii::$app->formatter->locale = 'ru-RU';
  echo Yii::$app->formatter->asDate('2014-01-01'); // output: 1 января 2014 г.
```

and or configure formatter components

```
return [
    'components' => [
        'formatter' => [
            'dateFormat' => 'dd.MM.yyyy',
            'decimalSeparator' => ',',
            'thousandSeparator' => ' ',
            'currencyCode' => 'EUR',
       ],
    ],
];
```